# How to get handle of the most recently opened window autoit?

Tags: autoit

I am trying to automate testing of an application. When opening the application it might open a pop-up window or security alert and I want to handle it. So is there a way to get handle or title of the most recently opened window in AutoIt?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to add some options. WinSearchChildren ...

## include

```
Example()

Func Example()
    ; Retrieve the window title of the active window.
    Local $sText = WinGetTitle("[ACTIVE]")

    ; Display the window title.
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", $sText)
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the time when a window was opened or maintain the order in which windows are opened?

Comment: You can put the check function into a loop and check all windows .. lets say every 250 ms without any noticeable effect on your CPU. All you need to do is compare the lists from now and from 250ms before :-)

Comment: Yeah, just use `WinWait("[REGEXP:.*Title.*|.*Title2.*]")` to wait for some windows to appear and handle them from there on... This doesn't use much CPU and immediately gets a result when a window with such a given title appears.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when needing to see a window "flash" every 60 seconds something was grabbing the focus, then changing back to the original window. I was able to write the following and capture the hi-jacker.

```
    ;what is the current active window

$Win1 = ""
$Win2 = ""
$Win3 = ""
$Win4 = ""
$Win5 = ""
$Win6 = ""


HotKeySet("{F1}","myExit")

while(1)
   $blah = WinGetTitle("[ACTIVE]")
   if $blah <> $Win1 Then
      $Win6 = $Win5
      $Win5 = $Win4
      $Win4 = $Win3
      $Win3 = $Win2
      $Win2 = $Win1
      $Win1 = $blah
   EndIf
   ToolTip("Last Active Windows: [press F1 to quit]" & @CRLF & "-" & $Win1 & @CRLF & "-" & $Win2 & @CRLF & "-" & $Win3 & @CRLF & "-" & $Win4 & @CRLF & "-" & $Win5 & @CRLF & "-" & $Win6)
   sleep(100)
WEnd

Func myExit()
   msgbox(0,"closing","closing program")
   Exit
EndFunc
```